# How to create dump file from Cloud 9 PostgreSQL database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cloud9-ide

I am now working on Cloud 9 and need to see my PostgreSQL database. So I hope to know the below two methods.

1. How to create dump file from PostgreSQL database when you know database name in Cloud 9?
2. Which tool can I use to see the tables of PostgreSQL database dump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html). It looks like Cloud9 doesn't permit remote PostgreSQL connections, so you'll need to run it within the workspace, then transfer the dump file to your computer. Use `pg_dump -Fc` to make a PostgreSQL-custom-format dump, which is the recommended format.

To list tables in the dump use `pg_restore -l` to list the dump's table of contents. Generally it's easier to work with dumps by restoring them to a local PostgreSQL install (again, using `pg_restore`) though.

For more detail see [the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html)